# Finding top 3 students in each subject MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have tried searching for ways to solve my problem, except that my database is set up differently,

My documents in my collection are something like this:

```
{name:"MAX",
 date:"2020-01-01"
 Math:98,
 Science:60,
 English:80},
{name:"JANE",
 date:"2020-01-01"
 Math:80,
 Science:70,
 English:79},
{name:"ALEX",
 date:"2020-01-01"
 Math:95,
 Science:68,
 English:70},
{name:"JOHN",
 date:"2020-01-01"
 Math:95,
 Science:68,
 English:70}
{name:"MAX",
 date:"2020-06-01"
 Math:97,
 Science:78,
 English:90},
{name:"JANE",
 date:"2020-06-01"
 Math:78,
 Science:76,
 English:66},
{name:"ALEX",
 date:"2020-06-01"
 Math:93,
 Science:75,
 English:82},
{name:"JOHN",
 date:"2020-06-01"
 Math:92,
 Science:80,
 English:50}
```

I want to find the top 3 students for each subject without regard for the dates. I only managed to find the top 3 students in 1 subject.
So i group the students by name first, and add a column for max scores of a subject. Math in this case. Sort it in descending order and limit results to 3.

```
db.student_scores.aggregate(
   [
     {$group:{
           _id: "$name",
           maxMath: { $max: "$Math" }}},
     {$sort:{"maxMath":-1}},
     {$limit : 3}
   ]
)
```

Is there any way to get the top 3 students for each subject?
So, it would be top 3 for math, top 3 for science, top 3 for english

```
{
 Math:{MAX, JANE, JOHN},
 Science:{JOHN, ALEX, JANE},
 English:{JANE, MAX, JOHN}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `sum` documentation? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Comment: @hisener
ohh, i think i get what u mean. 
I'm sorry, i did not phrase my question correctly.

I am not looking for max combined scores for each student. Instead, i want to get the names of top 3 scorers for math, top 3 scorers for science, top 3 scorers for english.

Comment: doyou want for specific case of those 3 subjects, or a general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but i can predict 2 scenario,

- **Get repetitive students along with date:**

---

- `$project` to show required fields and convert subjects object to array using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` subjects array
- `$sort` by subjects name in descending order
- `$group` by subject name and get array of students
- `$project` to get latest 3 students from students array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      date: "$date",
      subjects: {
        $objectToArray: {
          Math: "$Math",
          Science: "$Science",
          English: "$English"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$subjects" },
  { $sort: { "subjects.v": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$subjects.k",
      students: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          date: "$date",
          score: "$subjects.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      subject: "$_id",
      students: { $slice: ["$students", 3] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AEb9s6Ct3bo)

- **Sum of all date's score (means unique students):**

---

- `$group` by `name`, and get sum of all subjects using `$sum`,
- `$project` to convert subjects object to array using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` subjects array
- `$sort` by subjects name in descending order
- `$group` by subject name and get array of students
- `$project` to get latest 3 students from students array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      Math: { $sum: "$Math" },
      Science: { $sum: "$Science" },
      English: { $sum: "$English" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      subjects: {
        $objectToArray: {
          Math: "$Math",
          Science: "$Science",
          English: "$English"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$subjects" },
  { $sort: { "subjects.v": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$subjects.k",
      students: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id",
          score: "$subjects.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      subject: "$_id",
      students: { $slice: ["$students", 3] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MGEGy4fYPfc)

Comment: Thank You!! This is what I'm looking for, the first solution, except for the date. Sorry, my explanation of the problem isn't as good as I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I just applied your code 3 times, using `$facet`

If you prefer a more compact result add

`{$project:{English:"$Eng._id", Science:"$sci._id", Math:"$math._id"}}`

[PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lh3kMVTV_CK)

**PIPELINE**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "math": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            maxMath: {
              $max: "$Math"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "maxMath": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 3
        }
      ],
      "sci": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            maxSci: {
              $max: "$Science"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "maxSci": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 3
        }
      ],
      "Eng": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            maxEng: {
              $max: "$English"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "maxEng": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I'm looking for, never heard of $facet before.